# How to add new op in distributed Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to add a new op in distributed tensorflow. Following code is how I create a new operator which can add two array (following this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=np.float32)
array2 = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]], dtype=np.float32)

def add(array1, array2):
    return array1 + array2

add_op = tf.py_func(add, [array1, array2], [tf.float32])


sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(add_op)
```

Then I follow this tutorial(https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) to create a cluster of TensorFlow servers and try put an operator in it. I start the nodes, use the following code and command line.

```
#worker.py
import tensorflow as tf

# Configuration of cluster 
ps_hosts = [ "127.0.0.1:8887" ]
worker_hosts = [ "127.0.0.1:8888", "127.0.0.1:8889" ]
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})      

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("job_name", "worker", "One of 'ps', 'worker'")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("task_index", 0, "Index of task within the job")

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

def main(_):
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                             job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                             task_index=FLAGS.task_index)
    server.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

Command line:

```
# On worker0
python worker.py --job_name=worker --task_index=0

# On ps0
python worker.py --job_name=ps --task_index=0
```

Then execute this file to specify whether ops run.

```
#master.py

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def add(array1, array2):
    return array1 + array2    

with tf.device("/job:ps/task:0"):
    array1 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=np.float32)
    array2 = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]], dtype=np.float32)

with tf.device("/job:worker/task:0"):
    add_op = tf.py_func(add, [array1, array2], [tf.float32])


with tf.Session("grpc://127.0.0.1:8887") as sess:
    print sess.run(add_op)
```

But this code is not working, following is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "master.py", line 19, in <module>
    print sess.run(add_op)
  File "/Users/WakeUp/Repository/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/WakeUp/Repository/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/WakeUp/Repository/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/WakeUp/Repository/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to run py callback pyfunc_0: see error log.
     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0", _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](PyFunc/input_0, PyFunc/input_1)]]
     [[Node: PyFunc_S1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=-6409934414370243221, tensor_name="edge_8_PyFunc", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'PyFunc', defined at:
  File "master.py", line 15, in <module>
    add_op = tf.py_func(add, [array1, array2], [tf.float32])
  File "/Users/WakeUp/Repository/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 189, in py_func
    input=inp, token=token, Tout=Tout, name=name)
  File "/Users/WakeUp/Repository/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_script_ops.py", line 40, in _py_func
    name=name)
  File "/Users/WakeUp/Repository/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/WakeUp/Repository/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/WakeUp/Repository/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InternalError (see above for traceback): Failed to run py callback pyfunc_0: see error log.
     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], Tout=[DT_FLOAT], token="pyfunc_0", _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](PyFunc/input_0, PyFunc/input_1)]]
     [[Node: PyFunc_S1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=-6409934414370243221, tensor_name="edge_8_PyFunc", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

According to the N.B. in this page (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func), I think I didn't violate any rule of py_func function. Such as serializing the model or forgetting run `tf.train.Server` and `tf.device()`. Is there still something I didn't notice?

Comment: See caveats about py_func added in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/e3209bd34e12238f6993f104ef55d2aef618fe1a

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Hi, really thanks for your reply. I already read the caveats about the py_func function. Unfortunately, I still can not find the issues. So I updated more informations of how I run the code in my question. Can you give me some advices?

Comment: py_func nodes have to run on the client machine, in other words you can't run py_func on a remote worker

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov So there is no method that I can run the new op remotely?

Comment: No, Python ops have to be run locally, because they reuse the same Python interpreter that was used to create the graph

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Very thanks for your reply!